# Calendar Uneditable Event and change the navigation of date

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

https://developer.mozilla.org/fy-NL/demos/detail/html5-calendar/launch

based on the codes above it uses the browser's back/forward buttons to change day.
which of the codes make it do that? I can't figure out why.

and any advice how can I make the event that can't be edited out?

planning it to launch on a mobile application using phonegap

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. There you have a great starting point to become familiar with the history object.
If you have a look at the calendar.js from the above example they are using the History API very often.